# 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, angular, cors

Your issue seems to be that when you submit an Angular reactive form, the values are blank in the MySQL database. Can you please anyone help me to write proper code?

[image]

**My home component code**

```
formSubmit(){
    
      this.productService.insertUserData(this.myForm.value)
        .subscribe(
          (response:any) => {
            console.log('Data inserted successfully:', response);
            
            // Reset the form after successful submission
            this.myForm.reset();
          },
          error => {
            console.error('Error inserting data:', error);
          }
        );
  }
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      mobile: ["", Validators.required],
    });
}
```

**Product.services.ts file**

```
insertUserData(userData: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('https://mydomainname.com/quote/apis/upseradd', userData);
  }
```

**Home.component.html file**

```
<form
              [formGroup]="myForm"
              class="slideSix"
              (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()"
            >
              <h2>Fill the below form and get Quote</h2>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" formControlName="name" class="form-control" required
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" required
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" formControlName="mobile" class="form-control" required
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="nextBtn" [disabled]="loading">
                  <span *ngIf="!loading">Save and Continue</span>
              </button>
            </form>
```

**API**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "quote");

$response = array();
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    if ($con) {
        $name = $data['name'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $mobile = $data['mobile'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (name, email, mobile) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$mobile')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if ($result) {
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Data inserted successfully"));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Error inserting data: " . mysqli_error($con)));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Database connection failed"));
    }

?>
```

Your issue seems to be that when you submit an Angular reactive form, the values are blank in the MySQL database.`